# Java - Basic programming involving bits

Tags: java

I need direction to get started with a project. I have a binary file. Out of this file, I need to parse data. Now, I know length of each data; however, there are a few fields that are tricky. For example, there is an 8-bit field, in which the 4 least significant bits and 4 most significant bits represent different data. Are there any built libs available? Or do I have to use java bytebuffer and use bitwise operations?

Comment: Post your program so far

Comment: Smells like homework.  [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: You can read the file by means of plain InputStream and parse byte fields with bit shift operations. What is the problem? Please be more concise. You could post some example code.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the comments. It is not homework.

Comment: I am studying the requirement, have not started implementation. Just wanted to hear opinion from Java community if approach that @Fernando suggested is only way to do such a thing, or there is better way.

Comment: I am not aware of any libraries to do this. Since it's very easy to do with the basic language operators, i would not expect there to be any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitwise Operators: http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/bitops.html